# What is the history of the bounding box concept?

Tags: computational-geometry

A `bounding box`, if I understood correctly is a box that frames the box in which we work. It allows to align the box on the left, on the right, in the center.

Its use can be found in LaTeX package like `pgf/tikz`, `graphicx`, `tcolorbox` and certainly in other LaTeX packages as well as in the `Adobe Post Script` reference manual.

We do not find this notion, except error of my part in `LaTeX2e` written by L. Lamport.

From the historical point of view who (or what computer language) introduced this notion?

Is the concept of `bounding box` equivalent in all LaTeX packages? in all languages?

Comment: a bounding box is just a 3D "range". ranges have very long history in set theory, predating all computer languages.

Comment: @atb What do you mean by range? my machine translator doesn't always translate very well. https://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: for example: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Range.html